# Linux QT GCC OpenGL GLEW - add parameters to compiler

Tags: linux, qt, opengl, gcc, glfw

I want to create example GLFW file in C++.
When I type in Terminal `gcc FILENAME.cpp -lGL -lGLEW -lglfw` everything is OK,
but...
When I want to use CTRL+B to build my file in Qt Creator,
I see error `undefined reference to glfwInit`. I know I must add flags `-lGL -lGLEW -lglfw`, I tried to add `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -lGL -lGLEW -lglfw` in my `pro` file, but it does not work.

What is correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong variable. You want

```
LIBS += -lGL -lGLEW -lglfw
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by adding system library dependencies to your project (no QMAKE_CXXFLAGS needed).
If you have your project open, right-click the project name and select "Add library ...", the radio button "System package", "Next>", then type "glfw" for the package name ( or glfw3 to use the recent release ).
Do this two more times, adding packages "gl" and "glew".
You will see that the following four lines have been added to your project:

```
unix: CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
unix: PKGCONFIG += glfw
unix: PKGCONFIG += gl
unix: PKGCONFIG += glew
```

Now build (e.g. CTRL-B) and then you can run (CTRL-R).

I have just tested this and it worked exactly as the gcc command line did ( though I used glfw3 ).

Here is my complete project file:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui
TARGET = glwfeg
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += \
    ../glfwtest.cpp
unix: CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
unix: PKGCONFIG += glfw3
unix: PKGCONFIG += gl
unix: PKGCONFIG += glew
```

For glfwtest.cpp I just used the online "examples/simple.c" renamed.